# Sliding a UIView down with a CALayer bottom border

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I'm attempting to slide a UIView down when a bar button is clicked. So far, so good, but I've run into an issue. For aesthetics, I've added a bottom border to the view, and I want to animate this bottom border with the UIView sliding animation. The problem is that the CABasicAnimation is limited, not allowing for a CurveEaseIn. So, the bottom border slides quicker than the UIView.

How can I remedy this?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            _navView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 350);
            _navView.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 350);

            CALayer *oldLayer = [[_navView.layer sublayers] lastObject];
            CGRect oldFrame = oldLayer.frame;
            CGRect newFrame = oldFrame;
            newFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 350);

            // Prepare the animation from the old size to the new size
            CABasicAnimation *theAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"frame"];
            theAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
            theAnimation.duration = .5;
            // Make this view controller the delegate so it knows when the animation starts and ends
            theAnimation.delegate=self;
            // Use fromValue and toValue
            theAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:oldFrame];
            theAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:newFrame];


            // Update the frame of the layer
            oldLayer.frame = newFrame;

            // Add the animation to the layer
            [oldLayer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"frame"];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is almost certainly to use a view, not a layer, for your bottom border, and then animate the border view using UIKit instead of Core Animation.